# Creating table using eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to create a table using eloquent in Laravel. It is treating every integer attribute as `auto_increment primary key`.

Also while creating table definition, can I declare whether the field will be NULL or NOT NULL. Like attribute DOB is NULL, how can I declare this field `DOB` as `NULL` from here.

Model code block

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('devotees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('Category', 1);
            $table->string('NAME',150);
            $table->integer('GENDER',1);
            $table->string('BGROUP',4);
            $table->string('DOB',10);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Getting error as:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key (SQL: create table `devotees` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `Category` int not null auto_increment primary key, `NAME` varchar(150) not null, `GENDER` int not null auto_increment primary key, `BGROUP` varchar(4) not null, `DOB` varchar(10) not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lsapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458
```

How can I solve these two problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `integer` determine whether the column is an autoincrement field or not. See [here](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Schema/Blueprint.php#L643) for more details. So for your case, remove the second parameter like so And you can make a field null by chaining nullable method with it:

```
$table->integer('Category')
```

Or if you planned to use tiny integer, you can use this:

```
$table->tinyInteger('Category')
```

How to make a field nullable

```
$table->string('DOB', 10)->nullable();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   /**
     * Create a new integer (4-byte) column on the table.
     *
     * @param  string  $column
     * @param  bool  $autoIncrement
     * @param  bool  $unsigned
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
     */
    public function integer($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false)
    {
        return $this->addColumn('integer', $column, compact('autoIncrement', 'unsigned'));
    }
```

This is the integer() function from Blueprint.php. As you can see it expects a boolean parameter here. It looks like you're trying to add a argument for size. You cannot specify the size of integer in Laravel.

```
  Schema::create('devotees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('Category');
            $table->string('NAME',150);
            $table->integer('GENDER');
            $table->string('BGROUP',4);
            $table->string('DOB',10);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `tinyInteger` or just remove size parameter for integer field

```
$table->tinyInteger('Category');
// or
$table->integer('Category');
```